# Join points or draw lines between them on a torus

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

First I would have liked to map points and texture from a square map (box) in agent-based modellers to a torus.

```
StartShot = 
  ArrayPlot[NLGetPatches["covername"], 
    ColorRules ->  {"arable_land" -> Brown, "forests" -> Darker[Green]},
  Frame -> False, 
  DataRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

```
startingpoints = {{348.488, 132.622}}
agents = 
  ListPlot[startingpoints, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], White], 
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Axes -> None, 
    Frame -> False, 
    DataRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}];
Show[StartShot, agents, ImageSize -> 150]
paths = {{{348.488, 132.622}, {336.333, 63.6857}, {394.365, 24.5422},
          {39.3603, 78.1653}, {109.094, 84.2662}, {170.317, 50.3295},
          {195.403, 115.68}, {263.324, 132.615}, {316.947, 177.61},
          {381.382, 150.259}, {49.8526, 164.812}, {41.3217, 95.3342},
          {11.7384, 158.776}, {65.3616, 113.781}, {5.35985, 77.728},
          {18.7165, 9.01408}, {358.715, 372.961}, {394.767, 312.96},
          {340.367, 268.907}, {313.016, 333.343}, {269.92, 388.503}}};
arrows = {{{313.016, 333.343}, {269.92, 388.503}}}
lineplot = 
  ListLinePlot[paths,
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Axes -> None, 
    Frame -> False, 
    DataRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}, 
    PlotStyle -> White];
FlatTorus = 
  Show[StartShot, lineplot, agents,
    Epilog -> {White, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow /@ arrows}, 
    ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Then I map the 'box' - flat coordinates:

```
    dataTorus = paths/400*2 π;
    r1 = 1; r2 = 0.3;
    f[{θ_, ϕ_}] := {(r1 + r2*Cos[ϕ])*Cos[θ], (r1 + r2*Cos[ϕ])*Sin[θ], r2*Sin[ϕ]}
    Show[ListPointPlot3D[Evaluate[f] /@ Flatten[dataTorus, 1], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02]]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate@f[{\[Theta], \[Phi]}], {\[Theta], 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 
   2*\[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[FlatTorus]],
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)], 
 Graphics3D[
  Line[f /@ 
      Table[{Interpolation[#[[All, 1]]][k], 
        Interpolation[#[[All, 2]]][k]}, {k, 1, Length@#, .01}]] &@
   Flatten[dataTorus, 1] (*after george2079*), Boxed -> False], PlotRange -> All, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Question:

**I would like to connect my points with the shortest distances on the torus surface (in toroidal space) according to the order.**

Problems:

1. The interpolation put curves (yellow line)
2. The long line (red) is not a shortest distance, it happened because the line is drawn in euclidean space between the points. The interpolation is done in the euclidean space, not in the toroidal space. The distances should seems to be equals, like the geodetics on the sphere surface.

Comment: I think this would best be added to the Q linked by @DavidG.Stork above.

Comment: No, that's just good for texture. Please focus on the questions. How can I join the points on the torus surface? 
Why the strips are there?

Comment: Let me just say that you should attribute David's solution to him when you repost it like this, by mentioning him, linking to his profile and linking to his answer. All answers on this site are licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Perhaps, rather than using `StartShot` as your texture, you might rasterize `FlatTorus` and use that for your texture. Have not tried this myself, so it's only a suggested experiment.

Comment: Flattorus is a counterexample, when the line is drawn wrong - not till the border, and from the border in the other side.

Comment: @Pickett
@DavidG.Stork
I only added this `PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[StartShot]],
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, #4} &),Lighting -> "Neutral"] `, should I attribute that? Should I attribute all the little commands I learned? Please study the code a bit more; once David helped me, and I accepted his solution. Then other problems appeared.

Comment: @pnz1337 OK, I didn't know to what extent David had helped you. I only looked at his answer and noted the similarity. What I would do is, since this question looks very similar, to mention the other question and say that "I got help with that one, but now I have omse more problems:" People are voting to close this as a duplicate, which could be avoided if you acknowledge the other question and say what the difference between the two are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the path through your points like this:

```
Graphics3D[Line[f /@ Table[{
       Interpolation[#[[All, 1]]][k],
       Interpolation[#[[All, 2]]][k]}, {k, 1, Length@#, .01}]] &@
         Flatten[dataTorus, 1] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but the problem still exist. Please look at the modified question.

Comment: I think you've confused matters by lumping unrelated issues into one question.

Comment: Ok, I clarified the question. I think they were related by the way.